# Illustrator SVG how can I use only absolute coordinates

Tags: path, svg, coordinates, adobe-illustrator

I cant anywhere find how to set in Illustrator that I want to use SVG in ONLY ABSOLUTE coordinates. I found a lot of stuff about Inkscape as easy as this:

Change the preferences for 'SVG Output > Path Data' to always use absolute coordinates

But I need to use Illustrator. So please help me.

Comment: This is not possible using Illustrator's SVG output. Sorry. It would not be hard, however, to write a small JavaScript that loops through SVG path data and converts relative commands to absolute.

Comment: I wrote [a JavaScript function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9677885/convert-svg-path-to-absolute-commands/9677915#9677915) to convert a path in place to new data. After that you can output it as shown in the question, or use Chrome/Safari/Firefox's console with "Copy as HTML" to copy a new SVG snippt for use elsewhere.